# Having unexpected Error in Django EditView

Tags: python, django

When i hit the url i find all my fields are empty instead of having populated values, but when i try to edit them from django admin they work fine.I can see all my values there and when i can change their values also.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    choice = (('pending','pending'),('approve','approve'),('reject','reject'))
    test = models.CharField(choices=choice,max_length=10,default=choice[0][0],blank=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['name','test']
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/edit/',views.index),
]
```

## models.py

```
def index(request,pk):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        try:
            query = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
            print(query)
        except:
            raise Http404('0')
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=query)
        print(form)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(form)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

            return redirect('all')
        else:
            form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=query)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

## index.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

when i try to print each and every step, this step `if form.is_valid` shows no output.

There is no error though in console it works fine,doenst work the way i want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your if block as shown below:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(form)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Thanks @AbijithMg for commenting... but this is how we create post, it would simply create a form to populate it something with. It would create a new form instead of opening existing form.

Comment: Well, your question was not clear. You should have mentioned on GET request I need to populate the values!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Actually in order to edit i need to GET value from the instance. But my GET form was populated with request.POST means it was treating form as 'creating new form'. So,i removed request.POST and kept only instance=query, this is how i enabled my GET request to to get data from instance.

```
def index(request,pk):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        try:
            query = Post.objects.get(id=pk)

        except:
            raise Http404('0')
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=query)

        if request.method == 'POST':

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

            return redirect('all')
        else:
            form = PostForm(instance=query)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```